# Hadoop Eclipse Plugin Build Error

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 1.1.2, and I followed the steps to build the eclipse-plugin described in  http://surajit-paul.blogspot.com/p/eclipse-configuration-for-hadoop-112.html
But when I want to build the plugin, and running the `ant` command, I'm getting a long error list `[javac] 100 errors`:

```
ivy-retrieve-common:
[ivy:retrieve] :: retrieving :: org.apache.hadoop#eclipse-plugin [sync]
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [common]
[ivy:retrieve]  0 artifacts copied, 2 already retrieved (0kB/5ms)
[ivy:cachepath] DEPRECATED: 'ivy.conf.file' is deprecated, use 'ivy.settings.file' instead
[ivy:cachepath] :: loading settings :: file = /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/ivy/ivysettings.xml

compile:
 [echo] contrib: eclipse-plugin
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.xml:61: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 45 source files to /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/build/contrib/eclipse-plugin/classes
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/dfs/DFSFolder.java:28: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/dfs/DFSFolder.java:29: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/dfs/DFSPath.java:25: package org.apache.hadoop.hdfs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem;
[javac]                              ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/dfs/DFSPath.java:29: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/dfs/DFSPath.java:30: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/HadoopServer.java:36: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
[javac]                              ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/HadoopServer.java:38: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/HadoopServer.java:39: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/HadoopServer.java:40: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
[javac]                                ^
.
.
.
.
.
[javac] /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/HadoopJob.java:302: package Counters does not exist
[javac]       Counters.Group group = counters.getGroup(groupName);
[javac]               ^
[javac] Note: /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/server/JarModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 100 errors
```

I've searched a lot here and there, but nothing changed.
I'm new to `ant` or such other stuffs.
I really appreciate if someone could help me, or even please just upload your hadoop-eclipse-1.1.2.jar plugin, if you've got it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include all of the Hadoop dependencies. When you compile your hadoop program, it uses hadoop classes and to make sure the compiler can see those hadoop classes, you need to tell it where all of the Hadoop jars are located.

The following is an example of how you should modify your `build.xml` to set up the classpath using ant, but you will have to add in the complete list.  The complete list is all of the jars you included in eclipse, including any jars found in libraries that you added.

```
<property name="src" location="my/src/path" />
<property name="bin" location="my/bin/directory" />
<property name="lib" location="/path/to/hadoop/libs/" />
<target name="build" depends="init" description="compiling my hadoop program source">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${lib}" />
            <pathelement location="${lib}/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-*.jar" />
            <pathelement location="${lib}/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-*.jar" />
            ...
            <pathelement location="${lib}/some-other-jar.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! where shall I add these lines? the build.xml file in the eclipse-plugin directory?

Comment: Yes you should add those into your build.xml

Comment: shall I replace ${src} and ${bin} with a real address? or they are predefined variables?

Comment: I think you missed a </classpath> in your xml, right? I added all jars inside hadoop/lib as a <pathelement localtion="..." /> but I got the same error as before!

Comment: It does need the </classpath>, are you sure you have the right jars in the right locations? Make sure you are including the correct jars with the correct versions.

Comment: I used "ant jar -lib /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2" and all the errors gone, but it says BUILD FAILED and a warning afterwards: Warning: Could not find file /Users/majid/Desktop/hadoop-1.1.2/build/ivy/lib/Hadoop/common/commons-cli-1.2.jar to copy

Comment: So you are specifying the classpath directly through the use of the -lib option, this should be the same as specifying it in the build.xml.  The could not find file is the same classpath problem, it's looking for a jar and can't find it

Comment: yeah, but it should copy them automatically, in all instructions over the internet, no one tells about doing this... maybe I have to add them manually :) thank you anyway dear friend...

Comment: You are following someones walkthrough where they are copying jars into a common folder.  They then put that common folder in the build path.  I don't know why they would do this when they can just put the jars they were going to copy directly into the path itself

Comment: I've got a new error for MANIFEST.MF file, it says: [jar] Manifest is invalid: Manifest line "hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar," is not valid as it does not contain a name and a value separated by ': '. What shall I do?

Comment: oh I got it :) the problem was completely in MANIFEST.MF !! It's so sensitive, because any extra Enter character will cause a problem! also all Bundle-ClassPath entry values, should be in one single line and no enter between them!!! Thank you Mr. GreedyBuddha :)

Comment: Glad its working! Now you can finally get to the good stuff, actually using hadoop :)

Comment: Oh! even though it built successfully, but the final JAR file is just contains the MANIFEST file!! it's totally 776bytes !! so what do you think!! :) however, do you have the plugin? if so, could you please upload it? :)

Comment: No I don't, I've never used the eclipse Hadoop perspective, you don't need it to make hadoop programs.  I do use ant and know about path issues.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your consideration... :)